# structure of local ring with coefficient field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $(A,\mathfrak{m},K)$ a local ring with a coefficient field written $K$ for simplicity. Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ a minimal basis (a minimal set of generators in fact) of $\mathfrak{m}$ ie so that $\overline{x_1},\ldots,\overline{x_n}$ is a basis of $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ over $K=A/\mathfrak{m}$.

I'd like to know if in general one has $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]\simeq A$ from the evaluation morphism in $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

I think that $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ are algebraically independent over $K$ (adapation of Matsumura 14.5 with a coefficient field) so that $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]\hookrightarrow A$.

I don't see how to prove the surjectivity but it seems reasonnable. I know that $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]\simeq \mathfrak{gr}_\mathfrak{m}(A)$ maybe it could help.

My original problem is the claim that $A/\mathfrak{m}^2=K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1,\ldots,X_n)^2$ in lemma 1 after theorem 28.3 in Matsumura - Commutative Ring Theory.

Thanks for your help

Comment: No, consider any local ring of a closed point on an elliptic curve like $\Bbb C[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(y^2-x^3-x)$, for instance - what exactly is your original problem?

Comment: It is in the proof of lemma 1 page 216 in Matsumura Commutative Ring Theory where it is claimed that $A/\mathfrak{m}^2\simeq K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1,\ldots,X_n)^2$. Here it is supposed that $A$ is complete, maybe it is the missing hypothesis.

Comment: This lemma asserts that $A$ $\mathfrak{m}$-smooth over a field $k\subseteq A$ implies that $A$ is regular: first supposed that $k$ is pefect, then that $A$ is complete...

Comment: Sounds like you'd better [edit] your post to include the full context, then. Not everyone has a copy of Matsumura around (or is willing to go and get theirs to read your problem), and by explaining what you've written here in more detail, you'll have a better chance of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think I will repost a question because Peters's answer is interesting on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't true even if $n=1$.  Let $K=\mathbb{F}_p$, $A=\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at $(p)$ and $\mathfrak{m}=p\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ with $x=p$.  $p$ is some prime number.

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $p\in U$.  Let $A$ be the ring of germs of $C^\infty$ $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions at $p$.  Then $K=\mathbb{R}$, $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$ is generated by $n$ elements, but $A$ is not the polynomial ring.  It's not even Noetherian.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ does not have a coefficient field (it does not contain any subfields).

Comment: Define "coefficient field".

Comment: This is a standard definition: given a local ring $(R,\mathfrak{m},K)$ a coefficient field is a subfield of $R$ mapped isomorphically on to $K$ under the natural quotient map $R\to K$.

Comment: He didn't require $A$ to be a $K$-algebra to begin with...  He just said "local ring"

Comment: "Let $(A,\mathfrak{m},K)$ be a local ring with a coefficient field written $K$ for simplicity." This means $A$ contains a subfield isomorphic to $K$. But the ring $\Bbb Z_{(p)}$ does not contain any subfields, so in particular it does not contain a coefficient ring.

Comment: It's not true in dimension 1 even in the polynomial setting.  If $A=K[X]$ and f an irreducible polynomial, he's saying the localization of $A$ at $(f)$ is isomorphic $A$.  How can it be isomorphic?  It only has one maximal ideal while $A$ has infinitely many.