# Detail in Matsumura - Commutative Ring Theory - Lemma 1 page 216: structure of complete local ring with coefficient field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In Mastumura's book Commutative Ring Theory in the proof of lemma 1 page 216 is written that
$$ A/\mathfrak{m}^2\simeq K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1,\ldots,X_n)^2 $$
and I don't understand why it is true.

I explain the context:

Lemma 1: Suppose that $(A,\mathfrak{m},K)$ is a Noetherian local rink containing a field $k$. I $A$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-smooth over $k$ then $A$ is regular.

Recall: $A$ is $\mathfrak{m}$-smooth over B iff for all $B$-algebra $C$ with square zero ideal $N$, all morphism $u:A\to C/N$ with $u(\mathfrak{m}^k)=0$ for some $k$ lift to a morphism $A\to C$:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A @>>> C/I\\
@AAA @AAA\\
B @>>> C
\end{CD}

Proof of the lemma: take a perfect subfield $k_0\subseteq k$; then $k$ is 0-smooth over $k_0$ (because of separation of $k/k_0$: a previous theorem), so that by transitivity, $A$ is also $\mathfrak{m}$-smooth (a previous theorem), so that we can assume that $k$ is a pefect field. Also replacing $A$ by $\widehat{A}$, we can assume that $A$ is complete (because $A$ regular iff $\widehat{A}$ is regular). Then A has a coefficient field containing $k$ (previous theorem, recall: a coefficient field is a subfield of $A$ isomorphic to the residue field by quotienting with $\mathfrak{m}$). For ease of notation we write $K$ for this. If $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is a minimal basis of $\mathfrak{m}$ then as $K$-algebra we have
$$ A/\mathfrak{m}^2\simeq K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1,\ldots,X_n)^2 $$
Here is my problem!

The solution is [not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4159792/structure-of-local-ring-with-coefficient-field) $A\simeq K[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$. I think the hypothesis $A$ complete should be used but I don't see how.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is clearly a morphism of $K$-algebras $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1,\ldots,X_n)^2 \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{m}^2$ which is surjective.

By your assumption, $A/\mathfrak{m}^2=K \oplus \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ and by Nakayama $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ has dimension $n$ over $K$. So $\dim_K\,A/\mathfrak{m}^2=n+1$.

But $n+1$ is the dimension of $K[X_1,\ldots,X_n]/(X_1,\ldots,X_n)^2$ over $K$. So your map is an isomorphism.